# How can you parse the output of "tree" by levels?

Tags: command-line, disk-usage, tree

I have a raspberry pi attached to an external hdd as a small NAS for my home. I want to monitor the disk usage by directory, but with how slow the pi and the usb2 connections are and how big is the drive, any interactive disk usage program I found is too slow.

To solve that, I just set it to execute the following command

```
tree -ah --du > diskusage
```

But now I'm wondering, how do I parse the diskusage file so I can show all the directories in the first level, first and second, and so on.

EDIT: I am running the tree command on the latest version of Raspberry Pi OS and trying to parse it on either the same raspberry or ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu

Comment: Yeah, although parsing the file from ubuntu or raspbian I don't imagine can be any different.

Comment: The "normal" output of `tree` is formatted for a human reader - if you want to parse it I suggest using the JSON or XML outputs plus corresponding tools (`jq`, `xmlstarlet` etc.)

Comment: you mean `tree -L 1` ?

Comment: @bac0n No, because doing `tree -L 1` takes a long time, and if I want to do `tree -L 2` it will take the same time. I would want to do a `tree` call and save the output and use that instead since all the information is there.

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you! That looks like a very promising way to look for the information I need!

Comment: @metichi: Beware that `tree -L 2` will NOT give you the result that you are interested in: It does not add the disk size below the tree levels that it shows you. In general, the `tree --du` command always only shows the disk space consumed by the items that it shows you, not of any unseen child items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using qdirstat-cache-writer on that RasPi and importing the resulting file to your PC where you can view it at your leisure with QDirStat.

More details here:

https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat/blob/master/doc/QDirStat-for-Servers.md
https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat

HTH

--

Stefan Hundhammer (QDirStat author)

Comment: This seems like it will do exactly what I need it to do, examining the disk once and going deeper later on. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use this kind of command.

```
find / \
-maxdepth 1 \
-type d \
-exec du -sm \
--exclude="." \
--exclude="/proc" \
--exclude="/run" \
{} \;
```

where `du -sm` means summarize in megabytes

Comment: The problem with using du on each directory is that, unless I'm mistaking, calculating the size of a directory is only done by adding the sizes of every file inside recusrively. And as I said, that is very slow to do on my machine. For that reason I want to do the calculations once and then browse the result.